# Background tasks - How to run background tasks on a .net web application even if application has been stopped?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task, backgroundworker

Forgive me if my question doesn't make sense - i am new to multithreading in c# - I have an application that will run on iis server, i also want to implement some sort of background tasks that can be executed even if the application is not in use. For example in the application i want to have a method that will create the service/thread/task which will run in the background even if the application has stopped. Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: In-Process: No. If it's dead, it's dead. BUT: You could have a separate Service running in parallel (maybe not even on the same machine) that will be spoken to through some MessageQueue or "internal" API, for example.

Comment: i see - in terms of separate service - can you explain a bit further on how i could achieve this?

Comment: are you talking about a windows service?

Comment: Yes. With the latest project templates, they are fairly convenient and easy to create: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/workers

Comment: You may find this interesting: [Fire and Forget on ASP.NET](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html). Stephen Cleary has also published a [newer series of articles](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html "Asynchronous Messaging, Part 1: Basic Distributed Architecture") on the same theme.